# Top bar showing "NEW FEATURES" orange banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I noticed a banner saying there are new features in my top bar:

> [image]

When hovering over it:

> [image]

I'm not new, I already visited this new profile. Why did I get the banner? If it is intentional, what new updates are there to help improve the profile page or whatever thing you updated?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/ - happy reading! :)

Comment: I saw that little orange dialog on SO. It went away after a refresh even though I didn't click on it.

Comment: Screenshoted on a device with no camera... Nooooo!

Comment: Might be a bug, reworded and retagged.

Comment: Re your edit: this banner is meant for users who didn't visit or log in before the profile redesign. There's nothing new since then.

Comment: WHY IS IT IN ALL CAPS?

Comment: @bjb568 TO DRAW ATTENTION, obviously. :)

Comment: OK, I THINK I CAN SEE IT.

Comment: YEAH, THE ORANGE WASN'T ENOUGH...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the status of that indicator (whether you've clicked through it or not) is cached for 1 month. Given this was just rolled out a week ago, most folks still have it cached - but for folks who were testing it here on Meta, it may re-appear.

**Update:** Jarrod turned this off; everyone who needs to see it has seen it at this point.

Comment: But I never saw this before. I saw it one time with my main account today too and can't reproduce it anymore, so I used my sock just for sake of screenshot. Can you please check if it got bugged? (thought it's just me, but so far at least three others got it, and not only on MSE)

Comment: Checking... The dev responsible may be travelling, so please be patient.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in your case wouldn't that be a "shadow puppet"?

Comment: "I used my sock just for sake of screenshot" man, there's just nowhere they won't put technology these days.

Comment: I'll accept your answer just for the update... Thanks!